# Authentication flow slow on nextjs with localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have this authentication flow on nextjs in a layout component wrapping al my application routes. This is my code:

I have all the logic inside a useEffect and the return of this `<Layout/>` is any `{children}`

```
useEffect(() => {
      setLoading(true)
      const checkToken = async () => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('FBIdToken')
        //si hay un token en el localstorage
        if (token) {
          const decodedToken = jwtDecode(token);
          const res = await getNewToken();
          //Si el token expira
          if (decodedToken.exp * 1000 < Date.now()) {
            if (res.access_token) {
              localStorage.setItem('FBIdToken', res.access_token)
            } else {
              localStorage.clear('FBIdToken');
            }
          } else {
            if (router.pathname == '/login' || router.pathname == '/register') {
              router.push('/');
            }
            if (!userFromDB) {
              let user = await getUser(decodedToken.user_id);
              user.id = decodedToken.user_id
              //si encontro un usuario, lo asignamos al context api
              if (user) {
                //  obtenemos el objecto con los datos del usuario y seteamos en el context si es vendedor o no
                if (typeof user.isVender !== undefined) {
                  user.isVender ? setIsVender(true) : setIsVender(false);
                } else {
                  router.pathname !== '/suscripcion-request' ? router.push('/') : ''
                }
                setUserFromDB(user);
              }
              setAuthenticated(true)
            }
          }
        } else {
          if (allowedRoutesForEveryone.indexOf(router.pathname) < 0) {
            router.replace('/login')
          }
        }
        setLoading(false);
      }
      //comprobamos que haya un token y redirigimos al usuario en base a el
      checkToken();
    }, [router.pathname])
```

This is slow because the component returns the children and then checks if the users is logged in. This causes the redirect of private pages to be slow and it allows me to interact with the content for half a second before the redirect which is not very secure.

I know there are many libraries for this approach such as NextAuth or oauth2 but I don't know if there is one that allows me just to decode a token. Should I put this logic in a middleware? Something else?

I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you could not render it at all if it's going to redirect by using a loading spinner

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with `oauth2` or any authentication framework, but with how you have implemented the logic. If I understand correctly, your issue is that your component returns private pages before authenticating? This has nothing to do with authentication flows or frameworks, but a flawed logic on your "private page" components, which (it seems) are blindly rendering without checking if the user's authenticated. I would rewrite the question to be more specific, and explain how the private pages are rendered.

Comment: Also, remember that if your authentication flow depends on reading on localStorage, parsing a token, making a request... your authentication will be quite slow anyways because the client have to perform a lot of steps. Not exactly terrible, it's just a tradeoff.

Comment: The only logic I have on private routes is with `allowedRoutesForEveryone` but even with that it has to check if it has a token first and the loading didn't work with that amount of if's sometimes it doesn't stop loading or it cancelled before it finished

Comment: If you have the authentication done on the client-side (through `localStorage`) then you can add a loader to avoid showing the protected routes while the authentication occurs.

Comment: Another option would be to use cookies instead of `localStorage`, and move the authentication flow to the server-side/middleware.